# Помогите с LINQ To Entities запросом

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq

### База данных

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо с помощью Entity Framework из контекста базы данных `db` вернуть коллекцию Игр `Games`, первичные ключи `GameId` которых не используются в таблице `UserGames`.

Помогите пожалуйста, сегодня бошка не варит вообще.

### Попытка в linq

```
var userGames = db.UserGames.Where(ug => !ug.UserId.Equals(userId));
var games = db.Games.Join(userGames, g => g.GameId, ug => ug.UserGameId, (g, ug) =>
    {
    });
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам обязательно SQL и  Linq тоже подойдет?

Comment: linq нужен, обновил пост

Answer (score 0):

SQL-запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM Games
WHERE Games.GameId NOT IN 
(
     SELECT GameId FROM UserGames
)
```

LINQ - запрос:

```
from g in Games    
where !(from ug in UserGames    
        select ug.GameId)    
       .Contains(g.GameId)    
select g;
```

Comment: с первым запросом что-то не так

Comment: Исправил.Моя ошибка. Ох этот бесмертный враг CopyPaste!!!

Comment: не робит не робит не робит

Comment: Я исправил ответ. Попробуйте этот вариант.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT g.*
FROM Games AS g
     LEFT JOIN UserGames AS ug ON g.GameId = ug.GameId
WHERE ug.GameId IS NULL;
```

---

**UPD**

```
var query = from g in Games 
            join ug in UserGames 
                on g.GameId equals ug.GameId into g_ug
            from ug in g_ug.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where ug == null
            select g;
```

Comment: переведите на LIQN EF запрос, пожалуйста

Comment: что не так, аноним?